# trying to swap img with another using jquery

Tags: jquery

I've already asked one question and basically my code is fine I think.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".colorDiv").mouseover(function(){
        var image = $(this).attr("src");
        $(this).css("border", "2px solid #2F4F4F");
        $(".mPhoto[src='photos/WP_20140621_002.jpg']").replaceWith(image);
    });
    $(".colorDiv").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css("border", "none");
    })
});
```

what I need is the imgs in the .colorDiv class divs to replace the .mPhoto div.

what I'm getting is the .mPhoto img is disappearing being replaced by nothing any help would be appreciated.

I'm pretty new

Comment: `image` is a string, and you're calling `replaceWith` on that.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta do something like this:

```
$(".mPhoto[src='photos/WP_20140621_002.jpg']").attr("src", image);
```

This will take your new source (stored in the `image` variable) and place that in the `src` attribute of the `.mPhoto` class which has the old source you specified.

Just to be clear this would replace this line from your code:

```
$(".mPhoto[src='photos/WP_20140621_002.jpg']").replaceWith(image);
```

Comment: I tried the .attr() method but it is still not working I could really do with the help

Comment: What does "not working" mean? It would be much easier to help you if you put an example of your problem in something like http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: well last time the image was disappearing and nothing was replacing it. this time nothing is changing, for some reason the attribute isn't being changed. I haven't changed any part of the code accept the attribute function

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).on("mouseover",".colorDiv",function(e) {

        var image = $(this).attr("src");
        $(this).css("border", "2px solid #2F4F4F");

        $(".mPhoto[src='photos/WP_20140621_002.jpg']").attr("src",image);

});


$(document).on("mouseout",".colorDiv",function(e) {

        $(this).css("border", "none");

});
```

Comment: this doesn't change anything I get the same responce